# Transparent overlapping appbar

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, flutter-appbar

I'm trying to find a way to have a transparent appbar that overlaps the page content. I know I can use a SliverAppBar to show the appbar initially, and then have it slide out of view when scrolling, which is good. I can even give it a transparent background color. However, when you scroll to the top of the page, it always makes room for the bar to sit above the page content.

What I want is for the page content to be flush with the top of the page, as if there is no appbar, and then have a transparent appbar slide into view like a SliverAppBar does, so that I just have some action buttons overlapping the top of the page.

How can I pull that off? Is there a way to stack the appbar or change margins so it doesn't take space?

Comment: Well... you shouldn't be doing that, it is not recommended by any design language so better to avoid something like that.

Comment: is this for flutter or android jetpack compose or any other framework?

Answer (score 1):

You can just put a scaffold and your "page" in a `stack()`, make sure the scaffold is the last item in the stack. You can get creative an add animations for the app bars yourself or even use the sliver app bar, just make sure you use the same scroll controller for your app bar and content.

eg:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        // Your content
        Container(
          color: Colors.pink,
        ),

        Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("heading"),
            bottom: AppBar(
              title: Text("footer"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `extendBodyBehindAppBar`

this might do the trick:

```
Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
          elevation: 1,
          title: Text("my app bar"),
        ))
```